# Using jQuery to disable option value when option another option value is selected

Tags: jquery, html, sql

i want to disable price option value of 15 when page option value is selected to 1. The reason why it is disable is because the row that have value of 15 is called 1 time. here is the code of the option value

```
<td align="right">Select Page:
    <select name="page" id="page">
        <option selected disabled="disabled">Select</option>
        <option value="1"> 1 </option>              
    </select>
</td>
```

here is the option value for price

```
<td align="right">Select Price:
    <select name="price" class="calc" id="price">
        <option selected disabled="disabled">Select</option>
        <option value="15" class="calc" id="15"> $15 </option>
        <option value="10" class="calc" id="10"> $10 </option>
        <option value="5" class="calc" id="5"> $5 </option>
    </select>
</td>
```

this is my sql query

```
$ss = mysql_query("select page from images");//for getting the value
$r = mysql_query("select page from images");//for getting number of row
$a = mysql_fetch_array($ss, MYSQL_NUM);
$row = mysql_num_rows($r);
$result = $a[0];
```

and this is the jQuery that i using

```
<script>
    var $s = 1;
    var $page = $('#page'),
    $price = $('#price');
    $page.change(function(){
        if($page.val() == <?php echo $result ?>){
            if($s == <?php echo $row?>){
                $price.attr('disabled','disabled').val('');
            }else{
                $price.removeAttr('disabled');
            }
        }
    }).trigger('change');               
</script>
```

but it still not working. anybody can tell me why this is not working?

EDIT!
i havent determine the $price value in jQuery. how to put the value of 15 in the jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, a few things.

Firstly, you shouldn't use the function `.change()` as well as the trigger `trigger('change')`, choose one or the other.

Then you should place this script code in a `.ready()` function so that it is ready when the page loads.

Also, you can use the `[]` selector attributes to select all of the options at once, rather than iterating through them (I think this is what you are trying to do). Something like this as the final function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $s = 1;
    var $page = $('#page');
    var $price = $('#price');
    var $amt = '<?php echo $result ?>';

    $page.change(function() {
        var x = 1;
        if($page.val() == <?php echo $result ?>) {
            $("#price option[value!='"+$amt+"']").removeAttr('disabled');
            $("#price option[value='"+$amt+"']").attr('disabled','disabled').val('');
        }
    });  
});
```